# Go Lang: Very simple HTTP Post Requests and Response endpoint

Tags: http, go, request, endpoint

I know this is very basic, but perhaps someone can help me out. It's a very simple thing:

I have to run a endpoint with GO and it has to answer to HTTP Post requests...

The request body would look like:

```
{
  "answer": "ANSWER"
}
```

and the response body:

```
{
  "ac_token": "ACCESS",
  "re_token": "REFRESH",
  "type": "Bearer",
  "expires": 3600
}
```

I never used Go before and it would be very nice if someone could give me some hints how to solve this easy thing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: Have you made any attempt or done any research? Please show what you've got so far.

Answer (score 2):

Without an idea of how much code you've written as a starting point it's difficult to provide hints, but I can point you in the direction of some useful places to get started with http in go...

Have you looked at some simple HTTP server examples? Such as this:

https://gobyexample.com/http-servers

Then you may want to follow a tutorial on how to build a REST API in Go such as this:

https://dev.to/moficodes/build-your-first-rest-api-with-go-2gcj

Specifically, your endpoint may end up looking something like this if it needs to handle a POST method (I've just taken and slightly modified some code from that tutorial):

```
func (s *server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        // DO SOMETHING WITH REQUEST BODY HERE
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"message": "post called"}`))
    default:
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"message": "not found"}`))
    }
}
```

Once you understand that it might be useful to look at the http package in a bit more detail for further specifics:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

Hope that helps.